# Why do these two methods not calculate the same work done in this thermodynamic process?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics

> An Ideal gas is taken through the cycle $A \rightarrow B \rightarrow C \rightarrow A$ as shown in the figure. If the net heat supplied to gas is 15J, the work done by gas in process C->A is..?

[image]

So, I did this problem in two methods and each one gives me a different answer.

**Method 1.**

Notice, $C\rightarrow A$ forms a straight line, hence,

$ V= \frac{ \Delta V}{ \Delta P} P + C$

so, slope is '5'

$ V= \frac{1}{5} P +C$

now, work is

$$ W = \int P dV = \int P d( \frac{1}{5} P +C) =\frac{1}{5} \int P dP = \frac{\Delta P^2}{10} =\frac{5^2 -10^2}{10} = -7.5J$$

**The "other way" :**

Along path B-C, work is zero, now, applying fact that work over whole path is equal to heat supplied,

$$W_{A\rightarrow B} + W_{C \rightarrow A} = 15J$$

$$W_{A \rightarrow B} =PΔV =  5J$$

then work is $10J$

Which contradicts my previous answer (?), did I do something wrong or what's the reason for this paradox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is not well-posed.  For each complete cycle, the heat *into* the system should equal the work done *by* the system, because for a complete cycle, $\Delta U = 0$. The work done by the system *per cycle* is the area enclosed by the cycle.  For your cycle, the work done by the system is negative (note that you have unconventionally shown V(P) rather than P(V), so as drawn the enclosed area is negative.)  Since you specify that heat is *supplied* to the gas, this is not possible.

Assuming the direction around the cycle is just in the wrong direction or that you have reversed your P and V axes, we would next need to know the units of pressure and volume.  Assuming SI, the work done per cycle is 7.5 J (the area of the triangle), which still doesn't match Q, so we would have to assume the system goes through the cycle twice.  Or, if we assume the question is asking about what happens as the cycle is executed once, then the units must not be SI.

Answer (score 0):

If the area of the triangle ABC is 15 J (the work done in the cycle), the area of the trapezoid below CA is 3x as large (the work done during CA), or 45 J.  So the work done by the gas is -45 J for CA.